# Is it possible to declare identity function as a field in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, functional-programming

Currently identity function `java.util.function.Function#identity` is declared as a method that on each invocation returns new function.

```
static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
        return t -> t;
}
```

Is it possible to declare it as a field and still keep generics?

Comment: How exactly do you have a property which is also generic? If that was possible then `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` wouldn't be obsolete in favour of `Collections.emptyList()`

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. What are you *actually* wanting to achieve?

Comment: i want to have a function that transforms a stream (any stream) and i need only one such function. so i wonder if i can have it in a field instead of creating new one with each invocation (like the identity function)

Answer (score 1):

The `identity()` function returns a lambda and is not using `new xxxx`. I think the JDK implementation can determine what definition is returned, it isn't necessarily returning a new function each time as you suggest.

Consider this method:

```
public static void main(String...  args) {
    Function<String,String> f = Function.identity();
    Function<Integer,Integer> g = Function.identity();
    Function<String,String> h = Function.identity();

    System.out.println("f="+f+ " hc="+System.identityHashCode(f));
    System.out.println("g="+f+ " hc="+System.identityHashCode(g));
    System.out.println("h="+f+ " hc="+System.identityHashCode(h));
    System.out.println("f.equals(g)="+f.equals(g));
    System.out.println("(f == h)="+(f == h));
}
```

On my Windows and Linux JDK (19+20) this prints something like below which confirms same hashCode / reference from multiple calls to `identity()`:

```
f=java.util.function.Function$$Lambda$1/0x00000008010410f0@3a71f4dd hc=980546781
g=java.util.function.Function$$Lambda$1/0x00000008010410f0@3a71f4dd hc=980546781
h=java.util.function.Function$$Lambda$1/0x00000008010410f0@3a71f4dd hc=980546781
f.equals(g)=true
(f == h)=true
```

So, for these JDKs at least, there would be no point assigning the lambda as a field value in place of just calling `Function.identity()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have generic fields in Java. If you really wanted to use a field for the identity function then you could do something like the following:

```java
private static final Function<Object, Object> IDENTITY = x -> x;

public static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
    return (Function<T, T>)IDENTITY;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(identity().apply(1));
    System.out.println(identity().apply("one"));
}
```

however, as DuncG notes, there would be no benefit in doing so.